# Why Muslim Clerics forbade trip to Mars?

Tags: sharia, science

I recently heard on NPR that Clerics issued an fatwa that forbids going to Mars.

If it is taboo why?

Comment: A good read for the matter: http://muslimmatters.org/2014/02/25/how-mars-became-haram-a-guide-to-freaky-fatwa-news/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is an [Ijma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ijma) and is for safety, because *At the moment, there is no technology available that would allow for a return trip from Mars* ([source](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-57619288-1/fatwa-forbids-muslims-from-traveling-to-mars/))

In this [link](http://beta.slashdot.org/story/198505) you can find:

> The committee of in the UAE that issued the fatwa against such a journey doesn't have anything against space exploration, Elon Musk's Mars visions, or anything like that. Rather, the religious leaders argue that **making the trip would be tantamount to committing suicide**, which all religions tend to frown upon.

Perhaps, when there is enough advancement to make a round trip or if Mars is declared suitable for habitation, the consensus will be lifted.

Comment: I don't think the clerics have credibility to make statements about technology. They hardly know the current state and advancements, and future directions.

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac read the very first statement: _At the moment, there is no technology available that would allow for a return trip from Mars_ . Now look at the argument of the clerics: _making the trip would be tantamount to committing suicide_ . Even a third grade student will understand the risk.

Comment: I think parallels can be drawn with countries which advice their citizens NOT to visit certain countries because it may be harmful.

Comment: there is a difference between _harmful_ and _suicidal_. Moon trip is not deemed unlawful, because we know we can make a return trip from moon. But why Mars trip ?

Comment: There's a logical fallacy in this argument (at least in this shortness). Not being able to make a *return trip* from Mars back to Earth is *by itself* not tantamount to suicide: The fact that it is (currently) not possible to carry enough fuel for a return trip (or equipment to produce fresh fuel and rocket engines on Mars), does not necessarily mean that the transport of oxygen, water, food (or more likely equipment to produce them sustainably) is impossible.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen +1, ya, that's true. With advancement in technology such as [terraforming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Mars), [hydroponics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroponics), mars can sustain life, even eliminating the need of a return trip. However, the current status of mars one mission is suicidal. The astronauts will try to colonize mars, if they fail, they suffer unnatural death. Note that [fox news](http://www.foxnews.com/scitech/2012/07/24/is-mars-one-serious-about-suicide-mission-to-red-planet/) already declared it suicidal.